# Quarkus extension written in Kotlin programming language

Tags: kotlin, quarkus, quarkus-extension

I'm trying to write Quarkus extension in Kotlin and I'm not sure how to start.

I've already rewritten one service from Java to Kotlin and I know it's a matter of adding kotlin-extension as described in https://quarkus.io/guides/kotlin.

But what should I do when I want to write Quarkus extension in that language? Should I add dependency to kotlin-extension as well (is it even possible)? Or should I just add kotlin maven plugin?

There's some documentation here https://kotlinlang.org/docs/maven.html#specify-compiler-options but I'm not sure which approach is correct for my case. Do you have any code examples I could base on?

I've checked Quarkus documentation if there's any info on how to write Quarkus extension in Kotlin but I found nothing. I've also checked other sources like Kotlin documentation, github and youtube with the same result.